# Why does the code not show the numbers that are less than 15? Break loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, break, continue

a program that will iterates over each number in a the list then the if statement will check whether the iteration/number is greater than 15 then the loop will stop, otherwise the number from the list will be printed.
List = [1, 4, 7, 8, 15, 20, 35, 45, 55]

```
List = [1, 4, 7, 8, 15, 20, 35, 45, 55]
for i in List:
    if i > 15:
        break
    elif i > 1:
        continue
    print(i)
```

Comment: Because you're skipping your `print` with `continue`.

Comment: Your `elif` in practise skips the `print()` by executing `continue`.

Comment: please go  through [python break and continue statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: Your print statement is placed after the `elif` part. If your `if statement` is `false`, your `elif` will always run. Place your `print` inside your `elif` plus before the `continue`

Answer (score 0):

```
List = [1, 4, 7, 8, 15, 20, 35, 45, 55]
for i in List:
#print(i)
if i > 15:
    break
elif i > 1:
    pass
print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

Place your print statement inside the `elif check`.

```
List = [1, 4, 7, 8, 15, 20, 35, 45, 55]
for i in List:
    if i >= 15:
        break
    elif i > 1:
        print(i)
```

Comment: *continue* serves no purpose here